# Using circle rather than rectangle to define limit precisely

Tags: calculus, limits

Take a look at the following precise definition for limit

[image]

The geometric representation is

[image]

It is lucid that the definition of limit is the ability to find such rectangle (i.e. the intersect of blue and orange rectangles), if so, then the limit does exist. **My question** is is it possible to formulate the definition using circle rather than rectangle and if so how?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, no this isn't really possible, due to the fact that the "rectangular" definition most definitely needs to be a rectangle. You cannot force the definition to be "square", because this would enforce us to always choose $\delta \ge \varepsilon$. For many functions, (e.g. $f(x) = 2x$), this will not be appropriate, and you'd obtain a strictly weaker form of limit (one where $f(x) = 2x$ would have no limits as $x$ approached any point).

A "circle" shape has much the same problem: it doesn't allow for $\delta$ to be smaller than $\varepsilon$ (or whatever the "circular" counterparts would be), which it must be allowed to do.

However, I think we could do an elliptical version. That would be the obvious generalisation of the circle that we could work with.

Essentially, we want to start with a $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ as per usual, but we need to limit our function values differently. We need to not simply have $|f(x) - L|$ be less than $\varepsilon$, but have it be less than a function of $\varepsilon$ and $x$, or more precisely, the distance from $x$ to the point its approaching (let's say $a$). That function needs to draw out an ellipse with one axis width $\delta$, and the other width $\varepsilon$. Here's what we get:

> For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that
>   $$0 < |x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon\sqrt{1 - \frac{|x - a|^2}{\delta^2}}.$$

So, that's the "how". The above should be equivalent to the "rectangular" definition. I'll leave the "why" (or more particularly, "why not") as an exercise.